# Facebook SDK for Windows Store App?

Tags: c++, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-store-apps

I am using c++ to write a metro app. I don't' see anything in the Facebook SDK that I could easily use. What do I do in this case? I do have a functioning HTTP communication class written. Am I going to need to do this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found anything on the SDK level, but you can use the class here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker

to oauth with Facebook or G+, etc... There is a good example on MSDN.